# R - tidyr - spread() - dealing with NA as column name

Tags: r, na, piping, tidyr, spread

I am spreading multiple categorical variables to Boolean columns using `tidyr::spread()`. As the data contains NAs, `spread` creates a new column without a name.

What I'm looking for is a way to get rid off the NAs using

a) a piping solution (I've tried `select_()` and `'['()`, but don't know how to refer to the NA column's name or index) or

b) a custom function, which would be even better

c) a way to simply not generate the NA columns, Hadleyverse compatible, if possible.

Below is my current (and very inelegantly repetitive) solution.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

test <- data.frame(id = 1:4, name = c("anna", "bert", "charles", "daniel"),
                   flower = as.factor(c("rose", "rose", NA, "petunia")),
                   music = as.factor(c("pop","classical", "rock", NA)),
                   degree = as.factor(c(NA, "PhD", "MSc", "MSc")))

test <- test %>% 
  mutate(truval = TRUE) %>% 
  spread(key = flower, value = truval, fill = FALSE)
test[ncol(test)] <- NULL

test <- test %>% 
  mutate(truval = TRUE) %>% 
  spread(key = music, value = truval, fill = FALSE)
test[ncol(test)] <- NULL

test <- test %>% 
  mutate(truval = TRUE) %>% 
  spread(key = degree, value = truval, fill = FALSE)
test[ncol(test)] <- NULL

test
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `select` with `backquotes` for the "NA" column.

```
 test %>% 
    mutate(truval= TRUE) %>% 
    spread(flower, truval, fill=FALSE) %>% 
    select(-`NA`)
 #  id    name     music degree petunia  rose
 #1  1    anna       pop   <NA>   FALSE  TRUE
 #2  2    bert classical    PhD   FALSE  TRUE
 #3  3 charles      rock    MSc   FALSE FALSE
 #4  4  daniel      <NA>    MSc    TRUE FALSE
```

I guess it is difficult to not generate the NA column as the observations in other columns are tied to it.  We could use `filter` with `is.na` to remove the row that has 'NA' in the 'flower' column, but then we will lose one row ie. the 3rd row.

Answer (score 0):

As per @akrun's response, you can use refer to NA with backquotes. And here is a function to take care of it:

```
Spread_bool <- function(df, varname) {
# spread a categorical variable to Boolean columns, remove NA column
# Input:
#  df: a data frame containing the variable to be spread
#  varname: the "quoted" name of the variable to be spread
#
# Return:
#  df: a data frame with the variable spread to columns

  df <- df %>% 
    mutate(truval = TRUE) %>% 
    spread_(varname, "truval", fill = FALSE) %>% 
    select(-`NA`)

  df

}
```