# Why does spread() create a NA-only column?

Tags: r, tidyr, spread

I'm still an R beginner, so I hope this question is not redundant but I couldn't find a satisfying answer to my problem. Although [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33191137/r-tidyr-spread-dealing-with-na-as-column-name) seems to be very similar, I still wonder whether my observation represents the standard case. Using the funcion `tidyr::spread` results in an awkward behaviour when I try to spread three unique observations in one column that contain NAs. The result is a tibble with three new columns (as expected) but also with an additional fourth column named "NA" which is completely filled with NAs.

Here is my example dataframe:

```
test <- data.frame("Country" = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"), 
                   "Column1" = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2), 
                   "Column2" = c(3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5), 
                   "Column3" = c("B", "M", "F", "B", "M", "F", "B", NA), 
                   "Column4" = c(50, 74, 31, 53, 79, 33, 51, NA))

test1 <- spread(test, key = "Column3", value = "Column4")

test1
```

Is this normal when my tibble contains missing values? And if so, why? The creation of an additional column being completely filled with missing values as a standard behaviour seems strange to me. Or am I missing something obvious (probably)?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: That would be expected I think. `reshape` gives the same in base R. You have the values of `Column3` as your column headers in wide format, and `NA` is a value in that column.

Comment: It's what you would expect given your example data. You have `<NA>` as a key and its only value in `Column4` is `NA`, so that expands to all NAs.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yes, you are absolutely right. This was indeed a rookie question but I was really not aware that NA will be considered as an additional unique value.

Answer (score 1):

**spread** is behaving as expected, though the repeated presence of `NA` as both a column name and as values in the data frames might make the behavior unclear. Let's change the data frame to use a dummy value of `999` in "Column4":

```
test <- data.frame("Country" = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"), "Column1" = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2), "Column2" = c(3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5), "Column3" = c("B", "M", "F", "B", "M", "F", "B", 'NA'), "Column4" = c(50, 74, 31, 53, 79, 33, 51, 999))

  Country Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4
1       A       1       3       B      50
2       A       1       3       M      74
3       A       1       3       F      31
4       A       1       4       B      53
5       A       1       4       M      79
6       A       1       4       F      33
7       A       2       5       B      51
8       A       2       5      NA     999
```

And now the spread operation:

```
test1 <- spread(test, key = "Column3", value = "Column4")

  Country Column1 Column2  B  F  M  NA
1       A       1       3 50 31 74  NA
2       A       1       4 53 33 79  NA
3       A       2       5 51 NA NA 999
```

**spread** has correctly placed the `999` value in the new "NA" column (again, new column names taken from the old values in "Column3"), and aligned this value with matching values from the original data frame. Because `999` only appears once in the original data frame, it only has 1 matching row in the new data frame, and all other rows in the new "NA" column are therefore filled with `NA` (again, somewhat confusingly here).

Comment: Exactly. Changing the `NA` in `Column4` makes the result seem a lot less daft.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much! I feel kind of dumb now considering the fact that this makes total sense after your explanation. Indeed, `spread()` works as expected but I wasn't aware of how it handels missing values.